# Local Backup Solution for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, backup, enterprise

Is there an enterprise solution for backing up iOS devices locally instead of the cloud and also does not use iTunes? The goal is to have pure backup and restore functionality without allowing users to transfer personal data onto the device.

Answer (score 1):

I use iMazing fro Mac. It allows you to backup & restore individual iOS apps along with your custom saved data. You do that without going through iTunes.